# Receiving sms from customer then putting to database

Tags: sms

I am asking if this is possible or is there an existing service and what is it called?

We will have a raffle nationwide and for customers to be able to win they need to send us an sms. Is it possible that their text will go to a database located at net or something similar? And from there we will have random pick on the participants.

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Ok. Would any number work? How do I connect my code to my number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But it depends on where the SMS messages are sent. Are they just going to a phone or is it to an SMS service? If so, there should be some sort of API you can use to collect them and use the platform of your choice (PHP, Python, etc) to put it in a database.

Comment: Ah. Would any number work? Or should I consult a mobile network in our country? The idea is that the customers will text us (text with format) and we (the company I work for) will receive this then to put it in database. btw, what is the whole idea called?

Comment: There's a service called Trillio that should make the whole thing pretty easy.

Comment: Is that message for me? Haha. Tho I may email them just in case.

Comment: Yes, that was for you. You should be able to find all the info you need on their website.

Comment: So they're service is more than medicine notifications and not just for health-field professionals?